# Showing that $\|\sigma_n(f)\|_2\leq \|f\|_2$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $\|\sigma_n(f)\|_2\leq \|f\|_2$

(where $\sigma_n(f)$ is the sequence of Cesàro sums, that is, $\sigma_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}s_i(f))(x)$), where $(s_n)$ is some real sequence that converges to some limit $s$.)

Attempt/Thoughts:

\begin{align*}
&\|\sigma_n(f)\|_2\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}(\sigma_n(f))^2(x)\mathop{dx}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+t)\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}D_k(t)\right]\mathop{dt}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+t)K_n(t)\mathop{dt}
\end{align*}

(where $D_n(t)=\frac{\sin((n+0.5)t)}{2\sin((0.5)t)}$ is the Dirichlet kernel and $K_n(t)=\frac{\sin^2(nt/2)}{2n\sin^2(t/2)}$ is the Fejer kernel.)

\begin{align*}
&\|f\|_2\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x))^2\mathop{dx}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align*}

So now the problem is why $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x+t)K_n(t)\mathop{dt}\leq \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x))^2\mathop{dx}\right)^{1/2}$$

I also know that $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}K_n(t)\mathop{dt}=1$ so if I could somehow split the integral on the left hand side in such a way that $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}K_n(t)\mathop{dt}$ was one of the terms, then the left side would simplify considerably.

Edit:

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, I've simplified the left hand side of the inequality. But I can only simplify it to $\|f(x+t)\|_2$. Is there a way to show that $\|f(x+t)\|_2=\|f\|_2$? 
Any idea on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: I changed $||f||_2$ to $\|f\|_2$ and similarly for $\sigma$.  In some contexts this difference is even more conspicuous than it is here; for example notice the difference between $||f||||g||$ and $\|f\|\|g\|$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks. I didn't know there was LaTeX code for that symbol.

Comment: Plancherel's theorem gives this immediately since the magnitude of any Fourier coefficient of $\sigma_n(f)$ is always at most that of the corresponding Fourier coefficient of $f$

Comment: @Zarrax: I haven't heard of Plancherel's theorem, but I have noticed the similarities between my question and Bessel's inequality (if that's somehow related to Plancherel's theorem), where instead of the sequence of Cesaro sums $\|\sigma_n(f)\|_2\leq \|f\|_2$, a trig. polynomial is given $\|s_n(f)\|_2\leq\|f\|_2$. A quick google search of Plancherel's theorem says that it compares to Parseval's equation for Fourier Series, which I do know, but don't see how it's going to help here though.

Comment: The $k$th Fourier coefficient of $\sigma_n(f)$ is $(1 - {k \over n + 1})$ times the $n$th Fourier coefficient of $f$, so Bessel's inequality is enough too. (Keep in mind the explicit formulas for the $L^2$ norms of trig polynomials in terms of their Fourier coefficients.)

Comment: @SujaanKunalan : Nearly every sort of mathematical notation has a standard LaTeX code.  There are manuals on line listing them.